# Limit the installation of dependencies defined in setup.py

Tags: amazon-web-services, pip, setup.py, aws-cdk, python-packaging

If I look at the setup.py of [`aws_cdk.cloudformation_include`](https://pypi.org/project/aws-cdk.cloudformation-include/) you see a big list of dependencies;

```
  "install_requires": [
        "aws-cdk.alexa-ask==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-accessanalyzer==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-acmpca==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-amazonmq==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-amplify==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-apigateway==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-apigatewayv2==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-appconfig==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-appflow==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-applicationautoscaling==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-applicationinsights==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-appmesh==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-appstream==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-appsync==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-athena==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-auditmanager==1.85.0",
        "aws-cdk.aws-autoscaling==1.85.0",
         ...
```

All the aws-cdk libraries for the different services are defined here, but what if I only need `aws-cdk.aws-stepfunctions`?

Is there a way to limit the number of dependencies that we want to install? Or what could we suggest on this project to allow us to install only the dependencies we need? Maybe we can leverage [`extras_require`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html?highlight=extras_require#optional-dependencies) in the `setup.py`?

for example that we can do:

```
pip install aws-cdk.cloudformation-include[aws-cdk.aws-stepfunctions]
```

which installs the necessary dependencies + the stepfunctions dependencies

Comment: There is no straightforward solution, that I can think of. Your best bet is probably to install without dependencies: `python -m pip install --no-deps aws_cdk.cloudformation_include` and then install the dependencies you need.

Comment: @sinoroc I think your suggestion is the best approach for this, why no answer?

Comment: Another note, if you want move the dependencies to extras, you have to ask the package maintainers to implement the change (or do it yourself and open a new pull request). There's no way of changing the package metadata at installation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straightforward solution, that I can think of.

Your best bet is probably to install without dependencies:

```
python -m pip install --no-deps aws_cdk.cloudformation_include
```

and then install the dependencies you need.